# What is the html template use by symfony for file type field?

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I try to customize the **file** field in my form. Just as I do for other fields.

I simply overrid some parts of the html template (whatever it is, textarea for instance, or choice) ==> here the list of html template that make up any field [Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)

The fact is I cannot find the **file template** in the link. ([in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-customization-form-themes)  it is said to give all template for any field)

Any idea about how to customize the **file** widget?
[image: FILE_WIDGET]

HERE A DESCRIPTION OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACHIEVE:
I want the change the way is deplayed the html part which display the name of the file that has been chosen by the user.

Moreover, I am open about any find of suggestion about any methotology about how to customize this file widget. might be some other way of doing it... let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

As file input is just a simple `<input type="file">` it is rendered in `{% block form_widget_simple -%}` which you can easily find in `form_div_layout`.
If you want to change the view of this element you can change a bit `form_widget_simple` (from `bootstrap_3_layout`):

```
{% block form_widget_simple -%}
{% if type is not defined or 'file' != type %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim}) %}
{% endif %}
{{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

Or by creating custom block, as its [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-fragment-naming):

```
{% block file_row -%}
   {# file row template #}
{% endblock file_row -%}
```

Or if you want to customize only the widget

```
{% block file_widget -%}
   {# file widget template #}
{% endblock file_widget -%}
```